# Block Simplex Algorithm, i.e., Block Active Set for Linear Programming

Tags: linear-programming, simplex

What investigation has there been of Block Simplex Algorithms, i.e., block active set for Linear Programming, i.e., block pivoting? This is a follow-up to [Why do active set methods or the simplex method pivot only one variable at a time?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/27987/why-do-active-set-methods-or-the-simplex-method-pivot-only-one-variable-at-a-tim). This board was not yet in existence when that question was asked; and the question now seems better suited here.

It seems that (primal or dual) block active set has the potential to be much faster on some problems than (Primal or Dual) Simplex. As I and others suggested on the previous question, there may be a potential for cycling if block pivoting is performed.

Has anyone systematically investigated cycling in block active set, specialized in particular to Linear Programming? Are there certain rules (criteria) which would prevent cycling, but allow more than one variable to be cycled in or out of the basis at one time? Perhaps something in between always pivoting one variable at a time (Simplex), to always pivoting all variables having the requisite value of reduced cost (maximal block pivot)?

What could be said about use of Block Dual Simplex to solve node LP problems in MILP, which perhaps is the most important use case for LP Simplex (family) algorithms?

Even if there are no known criteria which provably prevent cycling in Block Simplex, might it still be better in practice than Simplex on some (many?) LPs?

Please post substantive answers, even if only addressing some of the questions.

Comment: Related: have you read chapters 21-23 of this book? https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-981-19-0147-8 . Or read Pan's other papers on face simplex method? It's specifically designed to try to avoid degeneracy alltogether.

Comment: Fundamentally, Simplex can be viewed as taking steps in a specific direction along the hull. If your step is the combination of multiple extreme rays, though, then it's not guaranteed to stay on the hull, right? That makes it more like interior-point.

Comment: @Brannon Block Simplex should hop from one vertex to a not necessarily adjacent vertex. It would not have iterates in the interior.

Comment: Related paper: https://digital.library.tu.ac.th/tu_dc/frontend/Info/item/dc:305422